# CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/.... the C++ compiler is not able to compile a simple test program

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, ubuntu-16.04, ninja

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:54 (message):
  The C++ compiler
  "/home/odroid/gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2017-q4-major/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++" is
  not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: /home/odroid/src/Firmware/build/px4_fmu-v3_default/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/ninja" "cmTC_b270d"

  [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_b270d.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj

  FAILED:
  /home/odroid/gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2017-q4-major/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++ -o
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_b270d.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj -c testCXXCompiler.cxx

  /home/odroid/gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2017-q4-major/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++: 1:
  /home/odroid/gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2017-q4-major/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++:
  ELF: not found

  /home/odroid/gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2017-q4-major/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++: 1:
  /home/odroid/gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2017-q4-major/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++:
  Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.


  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:263 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/odroid/src/Firmware/build/px4_fmu-v3_default/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/odroid/src/Firmware/build/px4_fmu-v3_default/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Error: /home/odroid/src/Firmware/build/px4_fmu-v3_default is not a directory
Makefile:200: recipe for target 'px4_fmu-v3' failed
make: *** [px4_fmu-v3] Error 1
```

I've been following a [tutorial dronecode](https://dev.px4.io/en/setup/building_px4.html), and I've gotten stuck on building px4 software step.  I have the ninja-build software downloaded as well as gcc compiler's downloaded and up to date.  I can't figure out what is going wrong here.

Comment: The command after *FAILED* is not able to compile a test file. Are you compiling natively on the device or cross-compiling?

Comment: I'm compiling natively

Comment: Ok so dig in there and figure out why the compile command doesn't work.

Comment: It looks like your system is trying to execute a native binary as a shell script.